# How do i display word with missing first letter?

Tags: python-3.x

i get a TypeError saying `can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly`

```
   # list of words to choose from and get a random word using the random module's sample method
   list_of_words = ['apple', 'banana', 'watermelon', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 'mango']
   word = random.sample(list_of_words,1)

   # showcase to the player the random word with first letter missing 
   chosen_word = word[1:]
   print('The answer so far is _' + chosen_word)
```

I expect the output to be for example: `The answer so far is _anana`

Comment: `word` is a list. of length 1. just pick the item from the list. ie `word[0][1:]`

Answer (score 0):

`random.sample` picks multiple random elements from the input sequence, according to the number given for the second argument. Because it is meant to return a variable number of elements, it returns them in a list, even if you specified that you only want one.

Therefore `word` is a list with one element and

```
word[1:]
```

is a sliced version of that list (the empty list), but still a list. The error message tells you, that you cannot add a list to a string by relying on an implicit conversion of the list to a string representation. What you  actually want to apply `[1:]` to is not the list, but the element in it. So you need to select it first with `word[0]` (take the first element of `word`), then you can slice the string: `word[0][1:]`.

If you always want only one element, you can also use `random.choice` instead of `random.sample`, which doesn't take the second argument and always returns only one randomly chosen element, not as list:

```
 word = random.choice(list_of_words)
 chosen_word = word[1:]
```